# How does this find command work?

Tags: find

I saw this example of a find command:

```
find -type f -exec ex -sc '%s/abc/def/g' -cx {} ';'
```

I understand everything up to -cx. what does:

```
{} ';'
```

mean? Is that part of the ex command or part of the find command?

Answer (score 4):

`It is part of the find command. From man find (at the actions part):

> -exec command {} ;

At the end, an example of the command line:

> find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;

The `{}` and `;` parts are escaped to avoid interpretation by the shell.
They mean:

```
`{}` The file name resulting from the find command.
`;`  End of command line executed by find.
```

In most modern `find` implementations you can also use `+` instead of `;` to indicate that `{}` should be replaced with as many arguments as possible for each invocation of the command.